# Disable datatpicker field from any input but keep onClick event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery Datapicker to input date

```
<div style="display: inline-block;"><input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of Birthday must be a date." data-val-required="The Date of Birthday field is required." id="Individual_DOB" name="Individual.DOB" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" /></div>
```

What I need is to disable keyboard input into the field, but to keep the onClick event to able to show the Calendar.

Is it possible to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a jQuery approach simply use:

```
$("#Individual_DOB").keypress(function(){
    return false;
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here's a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ws57/)

Answer (score 2):

asp.net mvc:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Birthday, new { @readonly = "readonly" } )
```

.

html input:

```
<input type="textbox" readonly="readonly" />
```